# Add \n to NSString or searching lines position in UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uitextview

I have plain NSString which i put into `UITextView` . I need to search position when new line starts. I think it can be done if textview converts string from 
`@"This is a big test string which i want to put into UITextView"` to `@"This is a\n big test \nstring which\n i want to\n put into\n UITextView"` automaticaly. Then i can search for "\n" and find position of some line . Any idea how can i do it ?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? You want to find where text is wrapped onto the next line by the text view? Why?

Comment: @Wain i compare some other part of text with text which stands in some manual line.If it can be done with this method it will looks like the text from \n to \n is the line. So when i say "compare this text to the text which stands on the second line of my textview" it must do it

Answer (score 0):

That's not the way how UITextView works. The process of laying out text in a container is more complicated than just finding line breaks and does not produce a new string containing NL characters.

On iOS 7 you could use the TextKit properties (`layoutManager`, `textContainer`, ...) of `UITextView` to access the underlying layout components and query them for positions of parts of your string.

If you have to support older iOS versions there's `characterRangeByExtendingPosition:inDirection:` in the `UITextInput` protocol. You can use it to calculate the extent of a line of text.

Comment: All my efforts to do this fails. Can you write me how can i get text (for ex.) from third line ? I am very thankful for your answer

Comment: @IgorPrusyazhnyuk Please show us what you tried. Where exactly are your problems using above APIs?

Comment: NSString* firstString; // assume big string
    UITextView* myTextView =[[UITextView alloc]init];
    myTextView.frame=CGRectMake(100, 100, 300, 400);
    myTextView.text=firstString;
    UITextRange* myRange=[myTextView characterRangeByExtendingPosition:[myTextView closestPositionToPoint:CGPointMake(10, 10)] inDirection:UITextLayoutDirectionRight];
    UITextPosition* myTextPosition=[myRange start];
    int position =[myTextView offsetFromPosition:myTextView.beginningOfDocument toPosition:myTextPosition];
'Anytime output is always 0. Assume 10,10 is the begining of line

Answer (score 0):

I count "\n"s in an app to know when to hide the keyboard. instead of counting \ns you can count the other chars to get your "\n" location. Rows just counts the number of "\n"s, and is reset to zero on view did load.

```
// dismiss keyboard from text view with return key
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range  replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {

        rows++;

        if ( rows >= 2 ){

            // resign text view
            [self.quotationTextView resignFirstResponder];

            return NO;
        }else{
            return YES;
        }
    }else{
        rows = 0;
    }


    return YES;
}
```

Comment: User will not input text to UITextView. I will get text from other resources which i can't change